# Dumb question about limitations to handle system related jobs

Tags: flutter

I am planning to make a launcher with flutter, I used to use flutter for other apps and didn't face a serious limitations. But with this project, I couldn't figured out how can get notifications from other apps or doing easy tasks such as mark as read or answer in app for whatsapp etc.

Also I am trying to make a music widget for playing songs from spotify etc. it is really challenging because play/pause or skip functions seems impossible. So flutter has serious limitations or I'm lack of knowledge about these matters? Is there any libraries to help on those or native flutter functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter is a powerful platform but when comes to controlling other apps' behavior, it has some limitations. But you want to response to WhatsApp messages in any other app, you can switch to native code through `ChannelMethods`

```
public class YourPlugin {
    public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
        final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "your_channel_name");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(new YourPlugin());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("your_method_name")) {
            // Implement your functionality here
            result.success("Your result");
        } else {
            result.notImplemented();
        }
    }
}
```

and then in Flutter

```
Future<void> invokeNativeMethod() async {
  try {
    final String result = await _channel.invokeMethod('your_method_name');
    print('Received result from native: $result');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error invoking native method: $e');
  }
}
```

And for notifications, you can explore [this](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications#-readme-tab-) package.
And if you want to play/pause or skip functions, you need to use [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package. You can also follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsRKXLsoTrA&ab_channel=MobileProgrammer) video.